# Can't Load Image from JSON

Tags: android, json, image, load

I want to display a list that contain text and image. 
The text and image stored on my online database, 
i using JSON for taking them down to my android app.

The JSON doesn't display any error, the text are displayed but the image are not appear.

I check the logcat and there's no error for this process. I using viewAdapter for displaying the image on the list.

Please help me, can you gimme some simple explanation how to solve this??

Thanks...

NB. This is my code for CustomListAdaper2:

```
public class CustomListAdaper2 extends ArrayAdapter<contenus> {
ArrayList<contenus> contenus;
Context context;
int resource;
public CustomListAdaper2(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, 
@NonNull ArrayList<contenus> contenus) {
    super(context, resource, contenus);
    this.contenus = contenus;
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
}@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position2, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout_layout, null, true);
    }
    contenus contenus = getItem(position2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageView5);
    Picasso.with(context).load(contenus.getImage()).into(imageView);
    TextView textViewtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtitle);
    textViewtitle.setText((replacehtml(contenus.getNom())));
    TextView textViewcity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewcity);
    textViewcity.setText((replacehtml(contenus.getVille())));
    TextView textViewtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtime);
    textViewtime.setText((replacehtml(contenus.getTime())));
    TextView textViewprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewprice);
    textViewprice.setText((replacehtml(contenus.getPrix())));




    return convertView;
}

}
```

this is my code for the json:

```
public class Multimedia extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<contenus> arrayList2;
ListView lv2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multimedia);
    arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView2);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ReadJSON().execute("http://wach.ma/mobile/category.php?id=Pour_La_Maison_Et_Jardin");
        }
    });
}

class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return readURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject contenusobject = null;
            try {
                contenusobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                arrayList2.add(new contenus(
                        contenusobject.getString("picture"),
                        contenusobject.getString("name"),
                        contenusobject.getString("city"),
                        contenusobject.getString("add_time"),
                        contenusobject.getString("price")

                ));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CustomListAdaper2 adaper2 = new CustomListAdaper2(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_list_layout_layout, arrayList2
            );
            lv2.setAdapter(adaper2);
        }

    }


    @NonNull
    private String readURL(String theURL) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theURL);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont use RecyclerView?

Comment: This line `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageView5);` doesn't look right. What is `imageView5` ?

Comment: @gilbertxenodike becaus i use the same code an other project and it works fine. the other project shows 1 image view and 1 textview. and this project must shows 1 imageview and 4 textviews. but it still doesn't shows the imageview!

Comment: @Neeraj imageView5 is the item in the layout for the image: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

Comment: So why is it `convertView.findViewById(imageView5)` and not `convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5)` ? Is it a static import ?

Comment: no, it's not a static, i fix it to"R.id.imageView5" but it still doesn't show images

Answer (score 0):

Just Edit This Code...

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id);
```

Otherwise everything is fine... I test it.

### Update

Before using url of the image be sure that

When you set the value you are assigning write position on the model contractor.

```
arrayList2.add(new contenus(
                    //is this "picture" is first argument 
                    contenusobject.getString("picture"), 
                    contenusobject.getString("name"),
                    contenusobject.getString("city"),
                    contenusobject.getString("add_time"),
                    contenusobject.getString("price")

));

//Or Check hare

String url = contenus.getImage();
Log.d("image url", url);
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

and what about `imageView5` is this right id for `imageView`?

Comment: yes. everything is fine. there is no error. but when i run it in the emulator it doesn't shows the images!